# Is there a way to hold an ImageView temporarily in a temporary ImageView?

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am trying to do something as follows in my program

```
ImageView temp = new ImageView(this);  //initialize beforehand somewhere in the program

ArrayList<Photos> photos = new ArrayList<Photos>(); //Photos has an ImageView that can be set via constructor

callBackMethod(YoutubeThumbnailView source){
    temp.setImageDrawable(source.getDrawable());
    photos.add(new Photo(temp));      //or just do photos.add(new Photo(source)) directly
    aMethodThatCallsThisMethodAgain();
}
```

What happens is that at every position in Photos ArrayList a photo() with the very last youtubeThumbnailView gets inserted.

Meaning when i retrieve it, all the positions have the same ImageView.

It only stores different ImageViews when i take unique temporary ImageView everytime.

e.g. 
temp1.setImageDrawable(source.getDrawable());  temp2.setImageDrawable(source.getDrawable());
temp3.setImageDrawable(source.getDrawable());..........

and so on.

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to recursion , it will of course set the imageview src to last one updated as variable name including the reference is the same

See when you insert temp imageview, a reference of that is stored to the new photos(temp) initialisation instead of full variable.Since the whole arraylist objects have the same temp as the references are same, I mean all your imageviews passed to new photos() method just point to same temp variable you have in memory, so any changes to temp causes change to all imageviews , you can test and see that

You can refer to hard copy/soft copy on stackoverflow to understand this better 
I would recommend you to create a new arraylist of imageviews and reference them to your photos constructor by index

```
ArrayList<Photos> photos = new ArrayList<Photos>(); //Photos has an ImageView that can be set via constructor

callBackMethod(YoutubeThumbnailView source){
ImageView temp = new ImageView(this);  //initialize beforehand somewhere in the program
temp.setImageDrawable(source.getDrawable());
photos.add(new Photo(temp));      //or just do photos.add(new Photo(source)) directly
aMethodThatCallsThisMethodAgain();
}
```

Comment: ok, lets say the Photos class has a constructor like  'code' public Photo(ImageView image){ this.Image = image } 'code' then why does it changes the ImageView value that is set at a particular Iteration even if the temp ImageView changes eventually?

Comment: it does not change it , you have to understand that all imageviews you are inserting refers or points to the same temp imageview which exists as one

please see new code in answer above

Answer (score 0):

what you have is a "bedside cabinet" with a single drawer and a cake box in it.

What you do is each tome you come along you throw away the old ccookies and fill in new ones.

Instead you should get a large side board with many drawers and put a new cake box in the next empty drawer each time you come along.

Translated to your code that means you need a `Collection` of `ImageView`s and add a new  `ImageView` object with each recursion.

---

> the drawer for temporary purposes and making it bigger is undesirable isn't it?

Its simply impossible. A "drawer" in my example is a place in the *list*. You can have just one item only at a distict position in a list. Tough this itemy bay be containers themselves, e.g. another `Collection` or an `ImageView`...

Comment: ok, but as i understand the drawer for temporary purposes and making it bigger is undesirable isn't it? I mean i have to take a huge Collection just so i can transfer my ImageView s to a Model class